# How to set type in typescript for some unknown data coming as object from api?

Tags: typescript, fetch, crud, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

```
 app.put('/update-user/:id', (async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
            const { id } = req.params;
            const filter = { _id: new ObjectId(id) };
            const user = req.body // Here data type is needed and typescript is showing error
            console.log(user);

            const option = { upsert: true };
            const updatedUser = {
                $set: {
                    ...user,
                },
            };
            const result = await userCollection.updateOne(filter, updatedUser, option);
            res.send(result);
        }) as RequestHandler);
```

The data of variable user coming as

```
interface Users {
    name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

But as it is a put method, the user data could vary. like it could add another key:value as age:29,
in that case how can i write iinterface with varaible object field?

I tried to introduce generic type. But could not make it as a newbie in typescript. Could anyone please help me write the correct interface?

Comment: What error specifically are you getting?

Comment: Unsafe assignment of an `any` value if  don't  use any type.  const user = req.body as User not showing any error. But my purpose is to introduce generic type as incoming data could vary.

Comment: This is express, isn't it? If so, what version?

Comment: yes it is. 4.18.2

Answer (score 0):

Typescript type system "disappears" at runtime, meaning that the type system should be seen as "hints" for the compiler/transpiler.

Typically, specifying a `User` type for your `user` constant should only be considered as a "hint" for the compiler: you will have no guarantee that this "hint" is valid/enforced at runtime (because `User` type will not be available at runtime).

It means that even if you tell the compiler that `user` is a `User`, then you will absolutely be able to put a response body structure which will absolutely not look like a `User`.
Nothing will fail during variable assignment (failures are going to happen downstream, when, for instance, you will try to access `User` properties which doesn't exist for real due to wrong (or partially wrong) type definition)

Keep in mind that there will be spaces where you will need dynamic typing with unknown type structures (response's body is a good example of it)

Typescript strength resides in the fact that the compiler will guarantee type assignments are "legit", but there will be area where you will need to "help" the compiler and express the expected types by yourself.

Comment: you will have no guarantee that this "hint" is valid/enforced at runtime (because User type will not be available at runtime). that's the important thing , it matters in this case. thanks